# Why dvorak's layout left home row is AOEIU?

Tags: layout, keyboard

I am trying to learn to type in dvorak keyboard, but I am having hard time with the vowels. I am ok with the consontants, but I am wandering why Dvorak didn't make it more simple to AEIOU for the left home row.

Is there a way mnemotechnical to remember the current position of vowels in dvorak layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboards layouts aren't optimized for learnability, but for speed of typing by expert users. Ease of learning also comes into consideration, but it's far from being the most important factor. Locations of letters are determined based on their frequency in the language, their relationships to other letters etc. So for example when key A usually follows key B, it's best to assign them to different fingers and possibly different hands. And since there are 26 letters in the English alphabet, there is a huge number of pairs to take into account, so it's hard to say why a specific letter is located on a specific key.

Same for QWERTY.

This may be an interesting question to post on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably makes more sense to locate the keys by frecuency, than easy to learn.

Comment: Except the QWERTY layout was designed to prevent the keys from binding, most keys are next to keys they are rarely used in combination with, and keys that are used often together are far away so the levers would not collide or bind during rapid typing...

Comment: @AthomSfere Yes, but the effect is the same - frequent pairs of keys are located away from one another, which increases hand/finger alteration, so it's optimized for both durability and human performance.

Comment: I type on Dvorak full time and I would say this is not quite right.  As an example the U(3% usage) character and I(6% usage) really should have been swapped in Dvorak but for some reason were chosen with their current locations for some reason.